# Post JSON as a string

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

Here is my js/ajax code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonObj),
        url: 'filter/GetAjaxTestResult',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
      }
    });
```

And I want to post `json` as string. here is what I tried in mvc/controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetAjaxTestResult(dynamic jsonString)
{
    return "";// Here jsonString is null!!!
}
```

How Can I get `json` as `string`? Is it possible?

Comment: Are you getting the value of jsonString in the action method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass it this way:-

```
  $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: "{'jsonString':'" + JSON.stringify(jsonObj) + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: 'filter/GetAjaxTestResult',
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function (data) {

            alert(data);
          }
        });
```

Another thing is your action's return type is JsonResult, i am afraid you cannot do return ""; you would need to return JsonResult, somethign like `return Json(...)`;

Comment: Yes that is because your serialized string should be passed in as json  object prop value with the same prop name as is defined in your action argument.